# Formidable Forms Submit Button/jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a program on a website that creates a graphic visual of 2 circles based on user input from a formidable forms calculator. I am using the field value on the actual webpage to create the size of the circle. Currently, the moment the user inputs the diameter and circle thickness, the graphic instantly updates and works fine. However, after hitting the submit/calculate button for the formidable forms calculator, the circles no longer update dynamically and I have to refresh the page to get them to work again. Also, I have the form setup using Ajax and on each submission/calculation. Is this a formidable forms issue or a Javascript issue? How do I fix this?

Actual webpage being used on: https://schallertenterprises.com/cutter-travel-calculator/

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/6rc9jbo3/109/

```
$(function() {
  $('.circle').hide();
  $('#outer_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
    var $converted = ($outer_diameter * 3.75).toFixed(3);

    if ($outer_diameter > 85) {
      $("#error").text($outer_diameter + " is too big").show();
      return false;
    }

    if ($outer_diameter < 0) {
      $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
      return false;
    }

    console.log($outer_diameter, $converted);
    $('.circle').css({
      height: (2 * $converted),
      width: (2 * $converted),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle').fadeIn(300);
    $('.circles').css({
      height: (2 * $converted) + 10,
      width: (2 * $converted) + 10
    })
    $('#error').hide();
  })




  $('.circle2').hide();
  $('#inner_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
    var $inner_diameter = parseFloat($("#inner_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
    var $converted_2 = (($outer_diameter * 3.75) - (2 * ($inner_diameter * 3.75))).toFixed(3);

    if ($outer_diameter > 85) {
      $("#error")
      return false;
    }

    if ($inner_diameter < 0) {
      $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
      return false;
    }

    if ($inner_diameter >= 0.33 * $outer_diameter) {
      $('#error').text('Wall Thickness invalid').show();
      return false;
    }


    console.log($inner_diameter, $converted_2);
    $('.circle2').css({
      height: (2 * $converted_2),
      width: (2 * $converted_2),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle2').fadeIn(300);
    $('#error').hide();
  })
  
});
```

Comment: your jsfiddle works fine even when clicking the calculate button but I can see the issue on your site, so could you update the code example to include the code for the calculate button as that must be doing something o cause the issue

Comment: The calculate button on the website is a built in submit button from Formidable forms, so is the entire entries/inputs on the website. None of it is my own code. Formidable forms allows you to reference entry field values to use in your own javascript code which is what I have done. However, when hitting the formidable forms submit button, those fields become null and the circles stop changing.